# Drawing a set of arrows in matlab

Tags: matlab, scilab

I have a series of "from" and "to" coordinates in 2D and I would like to draw in matlab a bunch of arrows that begin and end in those coordinates. How do I do that?

I tried `champ` but that didn't work.

Comment: what about the [annotation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) function?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a single arrox using the annotation function:
 h=annotation('arrow',[0 1],[0 1])

for a set of arrows, just loop

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `quiver` plot.

```
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

Plots arrows starting at (x,y) with the direction and length of (u,v). `x` through `v` can be vectors of the same length. One arrow is plotted for each of the elements.

Of course you first have to compute the displacement vector (u,v) from your start and endpoints.